# How to rename the files using bash script

Tags: bash

```
TOMCAT_FILE=/sys/project/apache-tomcat-8.5.47.tar.gz
if [ -e "$TOMCAT_FILE" ]
then
    echo "##############"
    echo ""
    echo "Installing Tomcat"
    tar zxf $TOMCAT_FILE -C /sys/project/
    echo "##############"
    echo "Tomcat Installation completed"
    mv  $TOMCAT_FILE/apache-tomcat-8.5.47
    echo "tomcat source file moved to apache"
    echo "Removing tomcat tar file from the current directory"
    rm -rf $TOMCAT_FILE/apache-tomcat-8.5.47.tar.gz
    echo "tomcat tar file removed"
fi
```

I have bash script to install tomcat, after installing tomcat tar file, i need rename the tomcat file like this (apache-tomcat-8.5.47 to apache), but when i running the scripts file renaming & deleting  is not happened when i am checking my source directory /sys/project/.

Can you please some one suggest me how to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mv $TOMCAT_FILE/apache-tomcat-8.5.47
```

cannot work since need to specify where you want to move it to, probably something like

```
mv /sys/project/apache-tomcat-8.5.47 /sys/project/apache
```

Comment: Failed again Installing Tomcat
##############
Tomcat Installtion completed
mv: failed to access '/sys/project/apache-tomcat-8.5.47.tar.gz/apache': Not a directory

Comment: @Anji I adapted my answer. please try to analyse yourself what might be the problem by  analysing the output. That will go faster than asking on stackoverflow each time.

Comment: Thanks lot Chris.